# TFVC and consequences of converting branches to folders

Tags: version-control, azure-devops, tfvc, git-tfs

## Setup:

I have a client with a TFVC source control repository.  The root is a folder, not a branch. Scattered throughout the hiearchy are branches, sometimes 2, sometimes 3 levels deep.  For using git-tfs to migrate the repository, I need the root to be a branch.  However, when I try to convert the root folder to a branch, I get this error:

```
You cannot create a branch at $/myProject because a branch already exists at $/myProject/Releases/7.3/Metadata. 
If $/myProject/Releases/7.3/Metadata is not a branch convert it back to a folder and retry the operation.
```

### Question:

Is there any impact to me "de-branching" some of those branches, turning them into regular folders, so that I can make the root a branch and then use git-tfs to migrate it?  Could I possibly lose some of the history? Would I be risking corrupting the source control repository or losing any data?  I'm trying to be very careful with the client's source code and not risk losing any data.

*Thanks!*

### Update:

My justification for thinking I need to convert the root to a branch:
* When created a simple test repository to try out the migration, and ran this command

```
git tfs list-remote-branches https://mysite.visualstudio.com/
```

I got this message

> "No TFS branches were found!"

And on [this](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues/495) github issue, it said I should switch to a branch, then I would see it and that worked.  So I assumed the clone wouldn't work since it didn't show up in the list.  Also, with the similarly structured test repo, when I ran git tfs list-remote-branches, I got:

> TFS branches that could be cloned:
>
> $/myproject1/Releases/7.1/Metadata [*]
>
> $/myproject1/Releases/7.2/Metadata [*]
>
> $/myproject1/Releases/7.3/Metadata [*]
>
> $/myproject1/Trunk/Main [*]
>
> Cloning root branches (marked by [*]) is recommended!
>
> PS:if your branch is not listed here, perhaps you should convert its
>   containing folder into a branch in TFS:   -> Open 'Source Control
>   Explorer' and for each folder corresponding to a branch, right click
>   on the folder and select 'Branching and Merging' > 'Convert to
>   branch'.

Based on that, I thought I had to convert it to a branch.
The next command I ran was

```
git-tfs clone https://mysite.visualstudio.com/ $/myproject1
```

I thought this gave me an error when the root was a folder, but it just gave me a warning when I reran it just now. The folder structure was something like
folder/folder/branch
folder/folder/folder/branch/folder
etc

> warning: you are going to clone the whole repository or too high in
>   the repository path !    => If you want to manage branches with
>   git-tfs, clone one of this branch instead :
>    - $/myproject1/Releases/7.1/Metadata
>    - $/myproject1/Releases/7.2/Metadata

So it looks like the reponses are right.  You can clone off the root without a problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to migrate the root folder to branch? Even if the root folder is not a branch, you can also migrate the history by `git tfs clone <URL> $/myProject`. And what's the command did you use to "convert the root folder to a branch" while got the error?

Comment: Thanks for the questions.  I will update my question with those details

Comment: I've provided an update to my question with this info, but basically because of the output of list-remote-branches, some users' comments I found on the interwebs and some of the output comments from the git-tfs tool.

Comment: I have updated my answer to give you another information...

Comment: @DanCsharpster `git-tfs clone https://mysite.visualstudio.com/ $/myproject1` will migrate all the versions of the TFVC repo into git default branch `master`. It will only show warning not error (as you found). And if you need to migrate certain TFVC branch, then specify the branch in `git tfs clone command`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't convert your branch to a folder.

What does the following command tell you to clone?

```
    git tfs list-remote-branches http://tfs:8080/tfs
```

A doc on the subject :
https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/manage_tfs_branches.md#find-the-tfs-branch-to-clone-optional

Edit: git-tfs is able to clone every folders in a TFVC Collection but if you want to clone the history with the branches, each folder should be converted as a branch.

Comment: I've updated my question with this output as it is too long for a comment, but basically it lists several of the smaller branches and then tells me I should convert the root to a branch.

Comment: Ah, gotcha!  That was the missing piece I was unsure of.  My client definitely wants their history.  So I will need to convert their nested branches to folders and convert the root branch to a folder, right?  Is there any downside to this?  Is there any risk of flipping folders and branches?  I don't want to compromise their repository.

Comment: As I know, no, there is no bad side effect to convert a folder in a branch. If I remember well, you could convert it afterward and it will work, but I'm not sure. I hope so for you.